# CMIS: cache data on server side

Tags: apache, repository, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm writing a CMIS interface(server) for my application. The server needs to load data from a database to process the request. At the moment I'm loading the same data for every request.

Is there a common way to cache this data. Are cookies supported for each cmis client? Is there an other chance to cache this data?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on cookies. Several clients and client libraries support them but not all. Cookies can help and you should make use of them, but be prepared for simple clients without cookie support.

Since your data is usually bound to a user, you can build a cache based on the username. But it depends on your repository and your use case what you can and should cache. Repository infos and type definitions are good candidates. But you should be careful with everything else.